# how to extract text that has already matched the multiple line pattern?

Tags: regex, vim, awk

all
using vim meta-character \_. or awk, I have matched the multiple lines, but I don't know how to yank or extract them into other files.Is there a general way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is applying to Vim, not Awk.

I can suggest:

```
function CopyPatternToRegisterZ(pat)
  let @z .= a:pat
  return a:pat
endfunction
```

And then:

```
:let @z = ''
:%s/your_pattern/\= CopyPatternToRegisterZ(submatch(0)) /g
```

Then you can use `"zp` to paste your matches to another file.

See `:help sub-replace-expression` for details on this syntax.

Comment: The need for `CopyPatternToRegisterZ()` is not necessary. Use `setreg('Z', submatch(0))` instead. If you want to do this linewise then `setreg('Z', submatch(0), 'l')`

Comment: @Peter Rincker: Does `setreg` return the value of the register? If not the replacement can cause some problem.

Comment: It returns zero on success and non-zero on failure. I see now why you created your own function. Although a simple `u` after running the substitution would accomplish the effect.

Answer (score 1):

use print in awk then redirect output to other file .

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS =" "};  { if ($0 ~ /(expression)/) { print $0 } }' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Only to copy pattern to another file

```
"between marks 
:'a,'b g/^Error/ . w >> errors.txt

"entire file
:% g/pattern/ . w >> log.txt

"to display "whit numbers", lines containing the desired pattern
:g/pattern/#
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Those commands copy lines, not multiline patterns!

Answer (score 0):

If you are at the start of the search, `y//e<CR>` will copy the whole matched string into default register. Note that after this action `n` will bring you to the end of the current search (because `e` offset flag is saved), if you want `n` to continue bringing you to the start, you should additionally type `//<CR>` (that clears all offset flags). So, the whole key sequence is

```
/<pattern><CR>y//e<CR>//<CR>N
```

Comment: maybe being explicit and use `//s` wouldn't hurt. So to complete your answer this can be recorded to a macro.